# PocketSphinx recognize any sound as word from dictionary

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi2, voice-recognition, pocketsphinx

I making gift to my friend, magic wand with voice recognition. in dictionary i have some spells like Lumos and Nox, but problem in that PocketSphinx recognize any word and sound as Lumos or Nox. How can i fix it? Can i check confidence % and filter, or something like that to stop recognize every sound like word.

Ex. i walk around mic and speaking with some one, and on display is something like 
LUMOS NOX NOX LUMOS LUMOS LUMOS NOX 
I doing it on Raspberry Pi 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [keyword spotting mode](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm/#keyword-lists), you can configure threshold for each word and they will be properly detected.